# Dice rolling program, but I need to transfer input data from a different class

Tags: java, dice

I'm trying to create a program that will roll 2 different die, that could either be automatically 6 sided or custom sided as decided by the user. As of right now I've gotten this far and need help figuring out how to get **anything** to happen from the `roll()` method, I've tried running it and it won't give me the **random int** it should.

Any ideas?

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
public class RollOfTheDice 
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {  Die firstDie, secondDie, face;
      firstDie = new Die();
      secondDie = new Die();
      face = new Die();
      face.getSides();
      firstDie.roll();
      secondDie.roll();
      System.out.println("First die roll results:.");
   }
}

class Die 
{  
    int numberOfSides; //field value


     public Die() //constructor
   {  numberOfSides = 6; 
   }

     public int getSides()//get method
   {  Scanner inputDevice = new Scanner (System.in);
      System.out.println("If looking for a custom sided die, please enter number of sides now:");
      numberOfSides = inputDevice.nextInt();

      return numberOfSides;
   }
      public void setSides(int Sides) //setmethod
   {  
      numberOfSides = Sides;
   }   

   public int roll() 
   {
      //return a random-generated integer value between 1 and amount of sides
      int rollResult = ((int)(Math.random() * 100)% numberOfSides + 1); 
      return rollResult;
   }
}
```

Comment: As a sidenote, calculation of result must be `(int)(Math.random() * numberOfSides) + 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you do not actually println your roll result ever.

So to get that basic output, you can change the last 3 lines of your main() method to the following:

```
  int firstRoll = firstDie.roll();
  int secondRoll = secondDie.roll();
  System.out.println("First die roll results:" + firstRoll);
  System.out.println("Second die roll results:" + secondRoll);
```

This should at least get you to show the two dice rolls.

Comment: Thank you!! I guess I was just making it more complicated than needed! I appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

Since an answer has already been accepted, I figured I'd give a few pointers;

```
    public int getSides()//get method
   {  Scanner inputDevice = new Scanner (System.in);
      System.out.println("If looking for a custom sided die, please enter number of sides now:");
      numberOfSides = inputDevice.nextInt();

      return numberOfSides;
   }
```

I recommend not doing IO during getSides() which then has a side-effect of setting the number of sides in your die.

instead, have the main method run the "askForSides" method (which contains the scanner). and then pass this argument into a setSides() method.

secondly, I recommend that instead of your current constructor which sets the sides to a fixed 6 you replace it with:

```
public Die() //constructor
{  
    numberOfSides = 6; 
}

public Die(int sides) {
    this.numberOfSides = sides;
}
```

Even better (well, I like it anyway) is:

```
public Die() //constructor
{  
    this(6); 
}

public Die(int sides) {
    this.numberOfSides = sides;
}
```

this way only 1 constructor actually sets the sides, the other simply supplies a default. this makes refactoring easier in the long run.

if you have a constructor that takes sides as an argument, you can use that instead of the setSides method :)

Comment: +1 for giving good advice that leaps out to experienced eyes when reading the code.

Comment: It's always great to hear some overall advice on my coding methods, I really appreciate the time you put in to help me out with simple stuff that overall will make an impact! Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1):

You did not simply forget to print out the actual value?

```
int first = firstDie.roll();
System.out.println("First die roll results: " + first);
```

Comment: Thank you!! I guess I was just making it more complicated than needed!

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `roll`, but not doing anything with the value that it returns.